# ElasticSearch/npm: elasticdump: Unexpected token error during dumping of response data

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

While dumping the output of an elastic dump command, unexpected token error occurred as shown below. What is wrong here? Do i need to pass in a different data type here? Is it possible to take a look at the response being parsed?

```
##>elasticdump  --input="https://<SERVER_IP>/elasticsearch/_search" --output="c:\edmp.log" --type=data
Wed, 24 May 2017 10:55:32 GMT | starting dump
undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elast
icdump\lib\transports\elasticsearch.js:52:21)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\e
lasticdump\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ela
sticdump\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\elasticdump\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:273:16)
```

Comment: Remove the `/_search` in your `--input` specification and only specify the index name

Comment: Thanks @Val - but what if i intend to capture everything for last 5 minutes using a query string filtered on gte attrib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `/_search` in your `--input` specification and only specify the index name, like this

```
elasticdump \
    --input="https://<SERVER_IP>/elasticsearch" \
    --output="c:\edmp.log" \
    --type=data
```

Now if you want to only retrieve data from the last 5 minutes you can also do it like this:

```
elasticdump \
    --input="https://<SERVER_IP>/elasticsearch" \
    --output="c:\edmp.log" \
    --type=data \
    --searchBody '{"query":{"range":{"datefield": {"gt": "now-5m"}}}}'
```